# Erro Entity Framework WPF Cliente

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, entity-framework-6

Instalei meu aplicativo no ambiente do cliente, mas estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

```
Nome do Evento de Problema: CLR20r3
  Assinatura do Problema 01:    eLogBook.exe
  Assinatura do Problema 02:    1.0.0.0
  Assinatura do Problema 03:    5a7e2d47
  Assinatura do Problema 04:    EntityFramework
  Assinatura do Problema 05:    6.2.61023.0
  Assinatura do Problema 06:    59ee4ce1
  Assinatura do Problema 07:    57cc
  Assinatura do Problema 08:    6c
  Assinatura do Problema 09:    System.InvalidOperationException
  Versão do sistema operacional:    6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
  Identificação da Localidade:  1046
  Informações Adicionais 1: 0a9e
  Informações Adicionais 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Informações Adicionais 3: 0a9e
  Informações Adicionais 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Só que coloquei todas as dll necessárias e que estão na pasta Debug do meu aplicativo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que pode ser isso?
Estou usando dois bancos de dados: Mysql e SQLCE, nos dois usando o EF6

Instalei o SQLCE 4.0 SP1 na maquina do cliente, mas continua o erro.

UPDATE 1: Consegui o seguinte erro com um log:

```
    System.InvalidOperationException: No connection string named 'remoteEntities' could be found in the application config file.
   em System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ConnectionHasModel()
   em System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   em System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   em System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   em System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   em System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   em System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   em System.Linq.Queryable.Select[TSource,TResult](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 selector)
   em View.MainController.validaStatus(String usuario)
```

UPDATE 2:

```
public bool validaStatus(string usuario)
    {
        try
        {
            var resultado = remote.Motorista.Select(x => new { x.ID, x.Login, x.Status })
            .Where(u => u.Login == usuario && u.Status == 1).ToList();
            if (resultado.Count > 0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            loc.LOGTexto("", e.ToString());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: em debug, qual é o erro? você implementou algum log para capturar exceções?

Comment: Não tem erro em debug, somente no cliente.

Comment: O problema está em `View.MainController.validaStatus(String usuario)`, em um trecho que busca Linq. Provavelmente um `Select()`. Precisamos do código deste método `validaStatus(string)` para entender melhor.

Comment: O erro diz que você não tem o arquivo app.config com uma connection string de nome 'remoteEntities'... certamente usada dentro do seu contexto remote ...

Answer (score -1):

Pela foto que você postou, parece estar faltando o arquivo eLogBook.exe.config na pasta onde você publicou sua aplicação.

O erro que está ocorrendo é porque a aplicação não reconhece sua string de conexão que fica armazenada nesse arquivo de configuração, justamente porque o arquivo não existe.

Comment: Isto não responde à pergunta. Quando você tiver [reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficiente, você vai poder deixar [comentários em qualquer post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) mas, até lá, escreva apenas resposta que não [dependam de mais informações de quem perguntou](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/159657)

Comment: @hugocsl entendo que minha resposta realmente estava incompleta e por isso editei, acredito que agora tenha ficado mais claro e seja possível ver que na verdade ela não dependia de mais informações da pessoa que fez a pergunta. Obrigado pela ajuda.